# _this.listCatModel.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown which I need to fill using this code :

```
 this.categoryService.GetListItem(this.GetAllcatListUrl).subscribe(data=>{
  this.listCatModel=data,
  this.listCatModel.push({
    id:0,
    name:'دسته اصلی',
    parentId:0
  })
});
```

and I need to `push` a value in `this.listCatModel`. But when I use this code :

```
this.listCatModel.push({
    id:0,
    name:'دسته اصلی',
    parentId:0
  })
```

I am getting the below error :

> ERROR TypeError: _this.listCatModel.push is not a function

whats the problem ??? how can i solve this problem ????

Comment: Whatever `data` is, it is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the array `this.listCatModel = []` first.

The `this.categoryService.GetListItem()` function is `async`, so it will not stop until you push the values to it.

Comment: u have to check the data if it is an array or not .